# How to have the list of code listings also in twocolumn?

Tags: listings, koma-script, two-column

I am using a KOMA class with option for twocolumn formatting. Unfortunately, the code listing using the macro `\lstlistoflistings` forces a change back to onecolumn format.

Please have a look on my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[%
  twocolumn=true,
  parskip=no,
  twoside=false
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifxetex % XeTeX (LuaTeX)
  \usepackage{default}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} 
\else % pdfTeX
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  inputencoding=utf8,
  extendedchars=\true,
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}


\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={class en Java},label={lst:class}]
public class MyClass{
  public MyClass(){
    // creates a new instance
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lstlistoflistings % buggy (ne marche pas en mode de deux colonnes)

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

Comment: What about using `multicols` from `multicol`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load package `scrhack`. Then `\lstlistoflistings` is under control of KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`, like the default lists. Additionally the settings of KOMA-Script option `listof` (e.g. `listof=flat` or `listof=totoc`) will affect `\lstlistoflistings` too. Note, that package `tocbasic` is used by each of the KOMA-Script classes automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass[%
  twocolumn=true,
  parskip=no,
  twoside=false
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrhack}% <- added
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifxetex % XeTeX (LuaTeX)
  \usepackage{default}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} 
\else % pdfTeX
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  inputencoding=utf8,
  extendedchars=\true,
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={class en Java},label={lst:class}]
public class MyClass{
  public MyClass(){
    // creates a new instance
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\lstlistoflistings
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```