# List of Listings (lstlistings) style in KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, koma-script, tocbasic

This post suggests that `scrhack` is required to format a list if listings consistently: [How to have the list of code listings also in twocolumn?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364399/how-to-have-the-list-of-code-listings-also-in-twocolumn) I would like to format my List of Listings consistently with my LoF and LoT by means of the KOMA-Script `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries` but I do not know what to use in between the `??`. I've tried `listing`, `listings`, `lstlisting`, `listlistings`

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
indent=-5ex,
numwidth=5ex,
entryformat=\normalsize,
entrynumberformat=...
]{tocline}{figure,table,??listing??}
```

`` Error:(81) tocbasic: toc style `tocline' needs toc style level. ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entry level name `lstlisting` does work. But because the level of entries of package `listings` has not been defined before, you have to set it. To give all three entries the same level, you can just use `level:=figure` or `level:=table`. This uses the level either of `figure` or `table`, which are already known:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
  level:=figure,
  indent=-.5ex,% negative?
  numwidth=5ex,%
  entrynumberformat=\textbf,% Should be a command with exactly one argument.
]{tocline}{figure,table,lstlisting}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\section{Test}
\captionof{figure}{Example figure}
\captionof{table}{Example table}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Example listing]
Test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

See the documentation of `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` in the KOMA-Script manuals from version 3.37 (or newer) for more information about `key:=value`. Note, that there must not be any space between `key` and `:` (but spaces between `:` and `=` seem to be ignored).

Comment: BTW: After I've reported this to the KOMA-Script author, [he has added new default for listings](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/Release%203.39/). So from next release option `level:=figure` will not be needed any longer in this example. However using `scrhack` will still be recommended.

Comment: Easy peasy--thanks for pointing out some other issues as well.

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of `:=`? Kind of like 'inherit'?

Comment: @likethevegetable From KOMA-Script manual, documentation of `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`:
”In addition to the usual assignment with `key=value`, both commands understand an assignment in the form `key:=entry level` for all options of the KOMA-Script styles. In this case, the current setting of `key` for the *entry level* will be copied. For example, you can copy the
current indent of the figure level using `indent:=figure`.” Note: There are also `+` options. See the manual for more information.